# SP2013 Datasheet View Webpart

Tags: 2013, web-part, datasheet, quick-edit

Have an SP2013 site that contains lists and pages with web parts that link to this list. One of the pages contains a Datasheet View what is used for a quick change in a particular field to kick off a workflow. This was working fine until recently, now the web parts no longer accept any of the edits. They would just revert to the original content, as well as displaying incorrectly. (ie drop down menus appearing next to cells instead of under)

However if the "Stop editing this list" option is used, and then the "edit this list" option it all works correctly.

I have attempted to recreate the web parts, the views, and even the pages. But all are experiencing the same behavior. Has anyone see this before? Have any insight as to what is causing this problem?